# The integration about the function $\ln(\cos πx)$

Tags: integration, special-functions

The problem is about how to integrate the function[image]

Here is what I did[image]

The stuck is that why we can get this
[image]

Comment: This isn't a physics question.

Comment: We'd prefer you use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations, not images.  It's the site standard.

Comment: What is $d^2 x$? See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341643/showing-that-int-01-log-sin-pi-xdx-log2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333941/how-to-computer-int-01-log-sin-pi-x-textdx-under-complex-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\int_0^{1/2}\ln\cos\pi x dx=\pi^{-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\cos y dy$ so $I=\pi^{-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin y dy$ and $$2\pi I =\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin y\cos y) dy=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin 2y dy-\frac{\pi }{2}\ln 2=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln\sin x dx-\frac{\pi }{2}\ln 2.$$ Hence $$2\pi I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin x dx-\frac{\pi }{2}\ln 2=\pi I -\frac{\pi }{2}\ln 2,$$ giving $I=-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$ as you obtained.